# How to select a specific previous row which meet some condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with PatientID, DiagnosisID and Date column. The scenario is that if the patient has come for same diagnosis multiple times in a month only the rows with a date difference greater than or equal to 3 should be counted as Visit Count for that particular month.

Example :

```
RowNumber PatientID DiagnosisID DiagnosisDate
1            P1         D1        29-12-2018
2            P1         D1        01-01-2019
3            P1         D1        05-01-2019
4            P1         D1        06-01-2019
5            P1         D1        08-01-2019
6            P1         D1        09-01-2019
7            P1         D1        13-01-2019
8            P1         D1        31-01-2019
9            P1         D1        01-02-2019
10           P1         D1        07-02-2019
```

1. Visit count should be counted as 1 for Dec-2018
2. DateDiff>=3 between 1st and 2nd row (29 dec and 1st Jan) hence 1st Jan 
   is valid Visit.
3. DateDiff>=3 between 2st and 3nd row (1st Jan and 5th Jan) hence 5th 
   Jan is valid Visit.
4. DateDiff<=3 between 3rd and 4th row (5th jan and 6th Jan) hence 6th 
   Jan IS NOT A VALID Visit.
5. DateDiff<=3 between 4th and 5th row (6th Jan and 8th Jan) hence 8th 
   Jan should be compared with previous valid visit i.e. 5th Jan here the 
   datediff>=3 so 8th Jan is the new valid visit and preceeding rows should 
   be compared with 8th jan.
6. DateDiff<=3 between 5th and 6th row (8th Jan and 9th Jan) hence 9th 
   Jan IS NOT A VALID VISIT.
7. DateDiff>=3 between 6th and 7th row (13th Jan and 9th Jan) hence 13th 
   Jan is new Valid visit.
8. DateDiff>=3 between 7th and 8th row (31st Jan and 13th Jan) hence 31st 
   Jan is new Valid visit.
9. DateDiff<=3 between 8th and 9th row (1st Feb and 31st Jan) hence 1st 
   Feb IS NOT A VALID Visit.
10. DateDiff>=3 between 9th and 10th row (7th Feb and 1st Feb) hence 7th 
    Feb is a valid visit.

Final output :

```
Dec-2018 visit count = 1 (29th Dec)
Jan-2019 visit count = 5 (1, 5, 8, 13 & 31st Jan)
Feb-2019 visit count = 1 ( 7th Feb )
```

Basically the Datediff between current row and prev row should be greater 
than equal to 3, if this conditiona is false current row should be 
compared with a previous valid visit.

I have tried it implementing it with recursive CTE, but I am not able to 
find a terminating condition i.e. the comparison should stop at previous 
valid visit.

Answer (score 0):

use LAG function to test DATEDIFF

```
WITH test_tab as
(
select RowNumber, PatientID, DiagnosisID, DiagnosisDate,
DATETIFF(day, lag(PlantFK,1,'19900101') OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID, DiagnosisID order by DiagnosisDate),DiagnosisDate) days
from table
)
Select * from test_tab ;
```

filtler >=3

```
WITH test_tab as
    (
    select RowNumber, PatientID, DiagnosisID, DiagnosisDate,
    DATETIFF(day, lag(PlantFK,1,'19900101') OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID, DiagnosisID order by DiagnosisDate),DiagnosisDate) days
    from table
    )
    Select * from test_tab WHERE days>=3
```

and group by Year/month

```
WITH test_tab as
        (
        select RowNumber, PatientID, DiagnosisID, DiagnosisDate,
        DATETIFF(day, lag(PlantFK,1,'19900101') OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID, DiagnosisID order by DiagnosisDate),DiagnosisDate) days
        from table
        )
Select YEAR(DiagnosisDate) year,Month(DiagnosisDate) montch,Count(RowNumber)
     from test_tab 
    WHERE days>=3
    GROUP BY YEAR(DiagnosisDate) ,Month(DiagnosisDate)
```

Comment: This compares Jan 8th to Jan 6th - the previous row. The asker is saying that this needs to be compared to the previous VALID row - the 5th. Not a correct answer to this question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I forgot to mention we need to implement it for 2008 R2 which does not support Lag function :( :(